# How to check if a process is an application or a service?

Tags: android

In android 4.0.4 there is not the same task manager widget than in android 2.2.

That's why I would like to make on by myself.

I have the code to list all the current processes, but, it would be cooler if I could list only the active applications as in the old task manager of android 2.2.

Otherwise, if I root my Android 2.2 phone, can I get the widget I'm talking about and install it on my Android 4.0.4 device?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out getRunningAppProcesses() and getRunningServices(int maxNum) in ActivityManager.